# Set default radio/input/checkbox value in AngularJS tabbed view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an AngularJS app using Ionic Framework which has a tabbed view with a Settings tab which will store user options for use. I want to use these settings when the app initially launches and while I could use the stored value in localStorage, I want to be able to check the options are set on the settings tab.

As it stands now, if you load the settings tab, you'll see one of the radio buttons sets itself from off to on as you load, and this is what happens whenever I set a default value that is on. How can I get this to be set when the app launches and not when the tab itself is opened?

This is what my controllers.js looks like:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if ( ! $window.localStorage.getItem( 'grossoption' ) ) {
        $window.localStorage.setItem( 'grossoption', 'year' );
    }

    if ( ! $window.localStorage.getItem( 'resultoption' ) ) {
        $window.localStorage.setItem( 'resultoption', 'month' );
    }
    });

    $scope.grossOptionsList = [
    { text: "Year", value: "year" },
    { text: "Month", value: "month" },
    { text: "Week", value: "week" },
    { text: "Day", value: "day" }
    ];

    $scope.resultsOptionsList = [
    { text: "Year", value: "year" },
    { text: "Month", value: "month" },
    { text: "Week", value: "week" },
    { text: "Day", value: "day" }
    ];

// Default values
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.grossOptions = 'year';
    $scope.data.resultOptions = 'month';


    $scope.updateGrossOptions = function(item) {
      $window.localStorage.setItem( 'grossoption', item.value );
        console.log( 'Gross option: ' + item.value );
    }

    $scope.updateResultOptions = function(item) {
      $window.localStorage.setItem( 'resultoption', item.value );
        console.log( 'Results option: ' + item.value );
    }

})

.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


    if ( ! $window.localStorage.getItem( 'toggle1' ) ) {
        $window.localStorage.setItem( 'toggle1', 'true' );
    }

    if ( ! $window.localStorage.getItem( 'toggle2' ) ) {
        $window.localStorage.setItem( 'toggle2', 'false' );
    }


});

$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.toggle1 = $window.localStorage.getItem( 'toggle1' ) === "true";
$scope.data.toggle2 = $window.localStorage.getItem( 'toggle2' ) === "true";

$scope.update_toggle1 = function() {
    $window.localStorage.setItem( 'toggle1', $scope.data.toggle1 );
    console.log( 'Toggle 1: ' + $scope.data.toggle1 );
}

$scope.update_toggle2 = function() {
    $window.localStorage.setItem( 'toggle2', $scope.data.toggle2 );
    console.log( 'Toggle 2: ' + $scope.data.toggle2 );
}
```

})
I've set up [**an example plnkr here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oyy5U1JxxkrfKGgUfUMF?p=preview) which shows the behaviour my app currently has when you load the Settings tab.

Appreciate any feedback on how best to approach this in Angular.

Comment: I don't think I understood your problem, your plunker seems to be working fine, it is always bringing the values specified in the controller as selected...

Answer (score 1):

you can use an "if" condition in the "ng-checked" like this:

```
<ion-toggle ng-checked="(myVar== 1)?true:false;" ng-change="myFunc(myVar)" ng-model="myVar" toggle-class="toggle-calm">{{myVar}}</ion-toggle>
```